# Extracting Cache Process information via SOAP in 2008.2

Tags: web-services, soap, intersystems-cache

What is the best way to configure Intersystems Cache 2008.2 so that the Web Service interface could be utilized to export a table consisting of the process information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
Class SSH.WS Extends %SOAP.WebService [ ProcedureBlock ]
{

/// Name of the WebService.
Parameter SERVICENAME = "SSHTEST";

/// Return process list with some additional info
Method GetProcess() As %XML.DataSet [ WebMethod ]
{
    set Dataset=##class(%XML.DataSet).%New()
    set Dataset.ClassName="%SYS.ProcessQuery"
    set Dataset.QueryName="SS"
    quit Dataset
}
}
```

You may use any query from %SYS.ProcessQuery, or create your own based on one of these.